# problems with adding column into a table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a declared parameter, say `@column_name varchar(200)`. I don't know how to add a column to a existing table with this column_name.

The following code has syntax errors.

```
alter table table_name add @column_name varchar(200)
```

Anyone know how do solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use dynamic SQL if your want a dynamic column name:

```
declare @column_name varchar(100)
set @column_name = 'col_new'
exec('alter table table_name add ' + @column_name + ' varchar(200)')
```